# Sympy returns empty result

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am attempting a very simple sympy example as following ;

```
from sympy import *
x,y,z = symbols('x,y,z', real=True)
expr = 256 * exp(-Pow((x-(y/2)/(z/2)),2))
solve(expr,x)
```

trying to get x in terms of y and z. Execution results in an empty list. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For what `x` is `exp(x)` equal to 0?

Comment: 0 or some other value

Comment: Do you have a right hand side, for example, are you trying to solve `256*exp(...) = 1` ? If so, add `-1` to expr, so that the right hand side becomes zero.

Comment: `exp(0)` is `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `fx = Symbol('fx', real=True)`. You will get `solve(exp(fx),fx) == []` because there is no real value of `fx` that can make `exp(fx)` zero. If there were such a value, say `fx = 2` then you could try `solve(fx - 2, x)` to find the value for `x`...but if there is no value for `fx` there is no value you can find for `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation doesn't have any solutions for `x` so `solve` returns an empty list. Here is your equation:

```
In [2]: expr
Out[2]: 
             2
      ⎛    y⎞ 
     -⎜x - ─⎟ 
      ⎝    z⎠ 
256⋅ℯ
```

When you pass that to `solve` you are asking "for what values of `x` is this expression equal to zero?". The exponential function `exp(t)` is nonzero for all possible complex numbers `t`. Since there are no finite values of `x` for which the given expression is zero `solve` returns an empty list meaning that there are no solutions:

```
In [3]: solve(expr, x)
Out[3]: []
```

If you make an equation that actually has solutions then `solve` can potentially find them for you:

```
In [6]: eq = Eq(expr, 1)

In [7]: eq
Out[7]: 
             2    
      ⎛    y⎞     
     -⎜x - ─⎟     
      ⎝    z⎠     
256⋅ℯ          = 1

In [8]: solve(eq, x)
Out[8]: 
⎡y          ________  y          ________⎤
⎢─ - 2⋅√2⋅╲╱ log(2) , ─ + 2⋅√2⋅╲╱ log(2) ⎥
⎣z                    z                  ⎦
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I missed the part where I had to define the function to some value or expression. I use ; expr.subs(y, 10) and expr.subs(z,15) to solve x for getting numerical values but I again get an empty list in return. Can I get numerical solutions for x when I put numerical values for y an z for this particular example ?

Comment: @user, `solve(expr,x)` is the same as `solve(Eq(expr,0), x)`.  Without an explicit `Eq` as in [6], it tries to solve for `0` value case.  That's what's giving the no solution.  Setting `y` and `z` to numeric values with `subs` doesn't address that issue.